# Multi-command shell AS detached child process WITH spawn() IN Node.js

Tags: node.js, multithreading, shell, child-process, spawn

For reference: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_detached

Hey guys,

So I need to `spawn` a child child-process, `spawn` because `exec` doesn't allow a `options.detached` & `child.unref();`, meaning it can be decoupled with the parent allowing the child to run and finish on it's own, vice-versa also the parent (in our particular case, the parent process can die before a long-running child, update in that case, is finished without needing to wait for the child like with exec).

We have a long connected `("… ; … ; …")` command that is built by the node (parent) app, but as like `spawn("echo stuff >>stderr.log")` doesn't work, only `spawn('ls', [-l])`, I obviously can't chain commands (as it's also referenced in he docu and multiple times on SO.

**TLDR;**

We need to use `spawn`, but `spawn` can't process chained shell commands.
*Do I really now need to write my command in a bash and execute that then, is this REALLY the ONLY option??*

THX

Comment: I'm not sure but if the first process's output is a `ReadableStream` then you probably can chain using `pipeTo` to the next process's input stream, that should achieve the same effect as `|`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice the `shell` option for [`spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options):

> If `true`, runs command inside of a shell. Uses `'/bin/sh'` on UNIX, and `'cmd.exe'` on Windows. A different shell can be specified as a string. The shell should understand the `-c` switch on UNIX, or `/d /s /c` on Windows. Defaults to `false` (no shell).

So:

```
let child = child_process.spawn('foo; bar; blah', { shell : true });
```

**EDIT**: if you're using a Node version that doesn't support this option, here's an alternative:

```
let child = child_process.spawn('/bin/sh', [ '-c', 'foo; bar; blah' ]);
```

Comment: I just wanted to answer, that we are tied to <= 5.x (which this wouldn't be available yet), but apparently we got to update our embedded board to 6.x just recently, YAY!

Comment: @ThaBrad for completeness' sake, I added an alternative for versions of Node that don't support that option.

Comment: thx so much. 
can't yet edit your post, but one tiny mistake -->`child_process.spawn('foo; bar; blah', [], { shell : true })` (arguments needed if options used, at least in TypeScript)

Comment: @ThaBrad ah I guess that's a TS thing, it's not necessary in plain JS (and also according to the docs, `args` is optional) :D

Comment: maybe, but probably because it is the second optional so it needs the first one to match it

Comment: @ThaBrad the implementation of `child_process.spawn()` checks if the argument is an array or not; if not, it's assumed to be the `options` argument.

Comment: ok probably one of the strange unJSy Typescript black spots :-/